# Upload images to a different static web server

Tags: php, webserver, image-uploading

I am building an application (PHP/Codeigniter/MySQL) where users can upload images. The main application will be on an Apache web server and all static files (images, videos, etc.) will be served from a Nginx web server.

Application Server : www.website.com

Static Server : static.website.com

Can anyone please whats the proper way to upload images to the Static web server? Links to the images will be stored on the main server, but the actual images are to be uploaded directly to the Nginx server.

Thanks

Comment: application server and static server are physically 2 separated servers or it is only one server and those sites are Virtualhosts? If it is separated, you could use some server side application like rsync

Comment: They are physical servers. I want images to be uploaded to the Nginx server in real time. Nginx server can also use PHP via PHP-FPM. Is it possible to write a script on the nginx server (API) and have a script on the Apache server send the file(image) to that script on the Nginx server?

Comment: @WebNovice What did you use? a script on nginx to upload image or any other tool like rsync

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please whats the proper way to upload images to the Static web server?

To upload them to an server side program running on a dynamic server, and have that program move the files to a suitable location for the static server to pick them up.

That might involve transferring them across a local network if the two servers run on different machines.